# Connеcted components of irreducible algebraic varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, polynomials, schemes, real-algebraic-geometry

I am wondering what is the possible (or maximum) number of connected components for an irreducible algebraic variety in $\mathbb R^n$ defined by a degree $d$ polynomial (i.e. hypersurface) in $\mathbb R^n$.

For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, how many (or maximum number of) connected components an irreducible curve defined by a degree $d$ polynomial in $\mathbb R[x,\, y]$ may have?

Comment: You can find some information about it here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/319241/41291

Answer (score 14):

For a (projective) *smooth* real plane curve $C \subset \mathbb{RP}^2$ the answer is known.

Such a curve is a compact smooth one-dimensional manifold without a boundary, so its connected components are diffeomorphic to circles and are called *ovals*.

If $\deg(C)=d$, a classical result by Harnack shows that the number of ovals cannot exceed $g+1$, where $g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$ is the genus of $C$. Moreover, the bound is sharp: curves with exactly $g+1$ ovals do exist, and are called $M$-*curves*.

For more information, let me refer to the paper

V. I. Arnol’d: [Distribution of ovals of the real plane of algebraic curves, of involutions of four-dimensional smooth manifolds, and the arithmetic of integer-valued quadratic forms](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01078120), *Funct. Anal. Appl.* **5**, 169-176 (1972); translation from *Funkts. Anal. Prilozh*. **5**, No. 3, 1-9 (1971), [ZBL0268.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0268.53001)

that can be downloaded [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/arnold13.pdf).